# Calculated column with ID removes ID number on update

Tags: list, custom-list, calculated-column

I'm using SharePoint 2013 and I have a calculated column in a custom list, called "Project ID" that has the following calculation:

```
="DS-000"&ID
```

The first item in the list has the "Project ID": DS-0001

When I make any changes to that record, the "Project ID" changes to: DS-000
Yet if I show the ID column, I can still see that it says "1".  The only way to get the value back is to edit the "Project ID", change nothing, then click "OK".  Once I do that, the ID number is back.

Any way to make that column retain the ID number after a change?

One caveat, I cannot use SharePoint Designer.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

ID is not valid column to use in Calculated Formulas, it is not displayed in the available columns for a reason.

- It is 0 for newly created items as it gets its value from the database **after** all Formulas are evaluated
- You get the correct values (in all existing items) if you re-edit the Formula
- It is reset to 0 on Item update (*I never investigated why*)

Only way is to get hold of that ID in a Workflow and save it to another Column

If you really can not use Designer.. *kinda like driving a Tesla, and not being allowed to use a charger*
You need a CSR or other Script that checks for 0 values in that Calculated Formula, gets the correct ID and writes it back... it is going to be duc-tape..

You can get the ID in the View in JavaScript:
[Get clicked item ID from list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/146955/get-clicked-item-id-from-list/147065#147065)

#### Update #1

If you can not use a workflow to get ID into a separate field your other option is to use a Client Side Script which checks for invalid=0 ID and updates your own field.
Major drawback is this script will not run immediatly for every item( like a Workflow can) but has to be triggered somehow.

- You can trigger by hand (code in a CEWP)
- You can trigger in a View (code in CSR or Calculated Column)

Second option can be 'instant' as from a New Form you (normally) end up in the Default View of the List.

iCSR iCC