# Calculated column showing hyperlink in list not working in SharePoint 2016

Tags: list, calculated-column, hyperlink, 2016

Let's say I have 2 items in a list. If I add a new calculated column with following code then it correctly displays hyperlink against those two items.

```
="<a href='http://sharepoint2016/sites/somesite/Pages/Default.aspx?k="&ID&"'>Some Link</a>";
```

This is how the link is displayed (just showing you URL that you see on hover):

```
http://sharepoint2016/sites/somesite/Pages/Default.aspx?k=1   

http://sharepoint2016/sites/somesite/Pages/Default.aspx?k=2
```

Problem is if I add new item from now on, after calculated column is created then it doesn't display ID of new item. It shows up like this:

```
http://sharepoint2016/sites/somesite/Pages/Default.aspx?k=
```

Unless I edit that list column and simply press OK to save it then it starts displaying ID for the newly added item correctly.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: You should not use ID in calculated columns: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159962/calculated-column-with-id-removes-id-number-on-update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Without a workflow

The ID is available in Table-Row HTML, so get that when you click the link:

```
="<a onclick=""{"   
&"var TR=this;while(TR.tagName!='TR'){TR=TR.parentNode}"    
&"var ID=TR.id.split(',')[1];"  
&"document.location='http://sharepoint2016/sites/somesite/Pages/Default.aspx?k='+ID;"   
&"}"">Some Link"    
&"</a>"
```

- [Get clicked item ID from list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/146955/get-clicked-item-id-from-list)

#### Shorter

This trick adds script to **every item**, so you want it as short as possible.

Since all SharePoint libraries have loaded by the time a user clicks,
you can use the SharePoint `GetAncestor` function:

```
="<a target=_blank "
&" onclick=""{"
&"  document.location='[your url]?k='+GetAncestor(this,'TR').id.split(',')[1];"
&"}"">Some Link"
&"</a>"
```

Answer (score 2):

The ID doesn't exist when the calculated column is calculated because the ID isn't generated until a new item is first saved. The easiest solution is to use a workflow that runs when new items are created to simply immediately edit the item (just log the reason in a comments field, if nothing else).